# How to plot a horizontal interval plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, intervals

I have a set of data points classified into 10 different types. Each type has its own range of values it can take. For example observation `x1` belongs to range `[10 12]`, `x2` belongs to range `[6 7]`, etc.

What I would like to do is the plot the different intervals of different classes into Matlab plot, like for example:

[image]

How could I do this in Matlab?  Is there a built-in function for this?

Thnx for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example to give you an idea:

```
X = rand(2,5)
Y = rand(1,5)
Y = [Y;Y]

plot(X,Y)
```

basically just put each separate line as it's own column

Comment: +1 But of course, sorry my question was a bit simple x) I got it now. Thank you!